# Is there a formal name for this graph operation?

Tags: graphs, terminology, combinatorics

I'm writing a small function to alter a graph in a certain way and was wondering if there is a formal name for the operation.  The operation takes two distinct edges, injects a new node between the existing nodes of each edge and then adds an edge between the two new nodes.  For example:

```
add new nodes a and b to the graph
let edge1 = (x,y), let edge2 = (u,v)

delete edge (x,y)
create edges (x,a), (a,y)

delete edge(u,v)
create edges(u,b), (b,v)

create edge (a,b)
```

Comment: I have seen the construction multiple times, but I have never come across a name for it.

Comment: I do this a lot and I'd love to know a name for it. In data modelling for databases, this is what you do when resolving many-to-many relationships (see e.g. Informix docs); the ORM term is objectification. But I also see it applied a lot to graphs in general, and always anonymously - e.g. in [Wikipedia's bipartite graph article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is like [subdivision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_%28graph_theory%29#Subdivisions). Actually you used two subdivision and finally you add extra edge between center of subdivision nodes.

Comment: The above method is not a subdivision, since the two new vertices are joined by a new edge.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect this. (question text wasn't clear at first).

Answer (score 0):

No.  No, there is not.  You can come up with one if you'd like.